# Add awk command bash script

Tags: bash, awk

I want to remove the dot from the display with a awk command but don't know how ?

My code

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/jeremy
touch home_pers_taille.txt
date>>home_pers_taille.txt
du -sh>>home_pers_taille.txt

cat home_pers_taille.txt
```

the dispaly

[image]

Comment: Some advice -- try not to `cd` from within your scripts ( `cd /home/jeremy` ) .. It can have unintended results based on the `user` executing etc ..  Instead try to use absolute paths within forked commands .. ( `touch  /home/jeremy/home_pers_taille.txt` ) OR store your directory in a variable and use it in your absolute path, if you find typing it out every time is cumbersome.  ( `touch $my_dir/home_pers_taille.txt` )

Comment: `du -sh | awk '{print $1}'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for awk, this is the kind of job `cut` exists to do:

```
$ du -sh
16K     .

$ du -sh | cut -f1
16K
```